# How can I set Chrome as default external browser in Eclipse for Mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos, google-chrome, ide

I think that question is self-explained :-)

When I browse to Application eclipse send me an error.

Comment: I can confirm that this problem exists in Eclipse Helios (3.6). I have Eclipse set up to use the default browser (Chrome), yet Eclipse always launches Safari instead of Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rubdottocom almost got it. The problem is, that the path contains spaces. If you write a new shell script with the following content:

```
'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' $1
```

Eclipse can launch a new Chrome instance with it. Sadly, this way it is not possible to open a new tab in an already running instance, as the script exits with the following error message:

```
[21043:2307:292361872340725:ERROR:process_singleton_mac.cc(102)]
    Unable to obtain profile lock.
```

Comment: For details on creating the shell script, and another possible workaround, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304854/is-there-a-way-to-add-google-chrome-as-an-external-web-browser-in-flash-builder-s

Comment: I can't believe an application and such a popular one as Eclipse, in 2012 still has problems with spaces in paths...

Comment: Sadly, thats more like normal even in 2012. The other problem is character coding (e.g. accented characters).

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to get Eclipse to recognize Chrome as the default system browser is :

1. Open Safari.
2. Go to menu Safari > Preferences > General.
3. Change 'Default web browser' to Safari.
4. Close the Preferences dialog.
5. Re-open the Preferences dialog.
6. Change 'Default web browser' to Chrome.
7. Close the Preferences dialog.

This solution is more general as it applies to any application which chooses the incorrect system browser. (thanks to Kelvin Lawrence at IBM)

I am using Eclipse 4.2.0 on an iMac with OSX Mountain Lion. This also works for Eclipse Kepler on Mountain Lion.

Comment: This works brilliantly! Safari's "Default web browser" was already set to Chrome when I installed Eclipse, but somehow Eclipse was opening Firefox as my default browser. Following John's instructions of setting the default to Safari, and *then* back to Chrome, did the trick.

Comment: Works with Flash Builder 4.7 as well.

Answer (score 10):

I posted the [answer on another question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304854/is-there-a-way-to-add-google-chrome-as-an-external-web-browser-in-flash-builder/8551375#8551375) on stackoverflow, so here it goes:

I found the solution in a blog's post that doesn't exist anymore, it involves configuring the Location to be '/usr/bin/open' and the parameter is '%URL%'.

You need to make sure that google chrome is your default browser and it will work properly. This is the only method that worked for me on OSX Lion.

Comment: Worked great on OSX 10.6.7, thanks! And even opens the page in a new tab reusing an open window instead of launching a new window.

Comment: This didn't work for me on OSX Mountain Lion. I had to use John Talbot's method.

Comment: Works very well on OSX 10.9 opening a new tab.

Comment: I love you. The only answer that worked on Yosemite.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by calling `/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" <url>`

Comment: This works great. Just go to the Eclipse preferences and search for the "Web Browser" preferences. Add a new external web browser and enter the following.
Location: /usr/bin/open
Parameters: -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" %URL%

Answer (score 1):

Ooops! I find the answer here: [Is there a way to add Google Chrome as an external web browser in Flash Builder Standalone for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304854/is-there-a-way-to-add-google-chrome-as-an-external-web-browser-in-flash-builder-s)

The exact location is:
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

It's annoying that you can't enter inside to an "Application folder" (AppName.app) through Finder :-S

Oh Wait! It's not working >_< Safari is opened

Comment: Yeah, tried it, doesn't work. With %URL% as parameter doesn't either. With quotes doesn't either.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try to fix that from eclipse at the menu bar: windows->preferences->general->web browser-> select the radio, Use external web browser and choose your default browser from there. that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helpful visual showing the `/usr/bin/open` techinque:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Finder, right click on *Google Chrome.app*, select *Show Package Contents* and browse down to *Contents/Mac OS* and drag *Google Chrome* to the *Location* in Eclipse's *Edit External Web Browser* dialog box. Enter *-url %URL%* in the field *Parameters*. This worked for me on Eclipse Indigo on MacOS 10.7, at least when Chrome was not started before...

Answer (score 0):

My method to set Chrome as a default browser in eclipse is:
Go to Window >> Web browser and then select Chrome.