# Whenever I set my the browser to DEFAULT WEB BROWSER(Chrome) in Eclipse, it shows an error. How can i rectify it?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, browser, eclipse-kepler

Whenever the browser in  Window->Web Browser is set to default web browser(Google Chrome), it shows an error on running the project. The error is "The file name,directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect". After the error, notepad opens up automatically.

Comment: Click on edit and check the location of the chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

I believe someone has already solved your problem:

[How can I set Chrome as default external browser in Eclipse for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322574/how-can-i-set-chrome-as-default-external-browser-in-eclipse-for-mac)

According to Zoltán Ujhelyi, it's because Google Chrome contains spaces in it's path.