# Zend Studio / Eclipse only uses Firefox for debugging

Tags: eclipse, browser, zend-studio

Somehow my Zend Studio / Eclipse only uses Firefox as external browser for debugging. I had Chrome all the time and Chrome IS my default browser!!!

Settings Zend Studio: General -> Web Broser -> "Use default system Web Browser" and "Use external Browser" is set.

Tried setting Firefox default and then Chrome again. Also rebooted and closed/opend Zend Studio a couple of times.

How the *** can this be???

I also tried adding Chrome as new  external browser, but I can't enter the "Location" path. On:
 /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome

it says "The location value is not a valid path name" *grRrrrr*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is either found here: [Is there a way to add Google Chrome as an external web browser in Flash Builder Standalone for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304854/is-there-a-way-to-add-google-chrome-as-an-external-web-browser-in-flash-builder-s)

Also works for Zend Studio in both ways, either using the Shell Script or editing the preferences XML

I used the following Shell Skript

```
#!/bin/sh
open -a 'Google Chrome' $1
```