# Cannot launch Google Chrome in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome

I cannot launch Google Chrome in my eclipse. I check my Preference/General/Web Browser setting, the location for Firefox is /Applications/Firefox.app, and it works fine. But for Chrome the path /Applications/Google Chrome.app doesn't work.

I have found similar problem in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304854/is-there-a-way-to-add-google-chrome-as-an-external-web-browser-in-flash-builder), but non of these answers work in my case. The running process just die after Tomcat is started and Synchronized. I am using Mac OS 106.8 and Eclipse Juno

Comment: Can you clarify how it's not working?

Comment: Here is the message from eclipse consol, it looks normal, I did not find any error message --------------------------------------------------------                                           
資訊: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
2013/8/20 下午 11:39:55 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
資訊: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
2013/8/20 下午 11:39:55 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
資訊: Server startup in 4288 ms

Comment: It also works with Safari, and the location is "/Applications/Safari.app"

Comment: It also works with Safari.

Comment: Solution is in the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322574/how-can-i-set-chrome-as-default-external-browser-in-eclipse-for-mac